# Python: Exploring data of GUI program

Tags: python, user-interface, variables

Is there ANY way( using python) to get values of variables stored in GUI? As an example to explain my question I will take a well known built in windows calculator. Lets say I type in it a value 245. It is easy to see this value when looking at calculator GUI display, but how can I make the python to get this value?

I have tried to use famous cheat engine to find in which memory adress this value is stored... without any result. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What platform? This depends a lot if you are under Linux (Gnome, KDE?), Windows, OS X, etc...

Comment: You edited the question after I posted my comment, that was not originally there.

Comment: Well actually it was. All i did edit was a layout but never mind i would be glad if somebodey could answer this question.

Comment: I won't continue to argue this, but it did not originally say 'windows calculator', just 'calculator'. You do not need to pretend it was there, you updated your question with the needed information, and that's fine. There is no need to take offence.

Comment: What's "famous cheat engine"?

Comment: -1 not nice behaviour for this community @user1354439

Comment: hmm cheat engine...are you referring to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_Engine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's wrap up this thread...

`pywinauto` will be your friend.

Sample case:

1. Launch Windows Calculator (calc.exe)
2. type a number in it, say `42`

This script will get and print you 42:

```
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application()
app.connect_(title='Calculator')
window = app.Calculator
print window.Children[5].Text
```

Homepage of pywinauto is [here](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/)

If you run on Python 2.7, you need to install and compile SendKeys yourself, or take useful information for this [page](https://bitbucket.org/orutherfurd/sendkeys/issue/5/windows-installer-for-python-27).